# Texture looks different in Cycles compared to Eevee or Material Preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

This is my material:
[image]

This is how it looks in Viewport Shading Rendered (Eevee):
[image]

This is how it looks in Viewport Shading Rendered (Cycles):
[image]

This is how it looks in Viewport Shading Material Preview:
[image]

This is how the render output looks (Cycles):
[image]

This is how the render output looks (Eevee):
[image]

Why does it looks so much darker in cycles? I want it to look more like in Material Preview/Eevee.
I'm not experienced with shaders. I didn't made this material myself. So, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Cycles, Evee, and shader preview render shadows, depth maps, lighting, and other things differently from each other.

Answer (score 2):

[Shader to rgb node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/shader_to_rgb.html) is for Eevee only.

The documentation mentions:

> Using this conversion breaks the PBR pipeline and thus makes the
> result unpredictable when **used in combination with effects such as**
> **ambient occlusion**, contact shadows, soft shadows and screen space
> refraction.

Edit: though, I'm not able to reproduce your issue...

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of things, changing the input here from B to A sloved it.

[image]

EDIT: Deleting the second Mix node in this image made it even better.